# Memory management for UIKit in tight loops under ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I'm interested in learning more about how best to handle memory management under tight loops with ARC. In particular, I've got an app I'm writing which has a `while` loop which rus for a really long time, and I've noticed that despite having implemented (what I believe to be) the best practices in ARC, the heap keeps growing boundlessly.

To illustrate the problem I'm having, I first set up the following test to fail on purpose:

```
while (true) {         
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"Foo"];
    [array addObject:@"bar"]; // do something with it to prevent compiler optimisations from skipping over it entirely
}
```

Running this code and profiling with the Allocations tool shows that the memory usage just endlessly increases. However, wrapping this in an `@autoreleasepool` as follows, immediately resolves the issue and keeps the memory usage nice and low:

```
while (true) {
    @autoreleasepool {         
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"Foo"];
        [array addObject:@"bar"];
    }
}
```

Perfect! This all seems to work fine -- and it even works fine (as would be expected) for non-autoreleased instances created using `[[... alloc] init]`. Everything works fine until I start involving any `UIKit` classes.

For example, let's create a `UIButton` and see what happens:

```
while (true) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectZero;
    }
}
```

Now, the memory usage increases ad infinitum -- effectively, it appears that the `@autoreleasepool` is having no effect.

So the question is **why does `@autoreleasepool` work fine for the `NSMutableArray` and keep the memory in-check, but when applied to a `UIButton` the heap continues to grow?**

Most importantly, how can I keep the heap from expanding endlessly when using `UIKit` classes in an endless loop like this, and what does this tell us about the best practices for ARC in `while(true)` or `while(keepRunningForALongTime)` style loops?

My gut feeling on this is (and I could be totally wrong) is that it's perhaps something about how the `while (true)` keeps the runloop from cycling, which is keeping the `UIKit` instances in memory rather than releasing them... But clearly I'm missing something in my understanding of ARC!

(And to eliminate an obvious cause, `NSZombiedEnabled` is not enabled.)

Comment: Of course the example with `UIButton` is pathological. The example with `@autoreleasepool` is a better test case and does work.

Comment: I imagine once you break out of that while loop the memory will be reclaimed. My advice would be to find another way of doing what you want to do. Perhaps you could break your task up into an `NSOperation`, a series of which can be put on an `NSOperationQueue` for serial execution.

Comment: @Zaph -- the `UIButton` case still uses `@autoreleasepool`
@jackslash -- yes, you are correct, upon exiting the `while` loop, the memory is reclaimed (already tested this by substituting the `while` with a long-running `for` loop)

Comment: So you have found that somewhere in UIKit, the `UIButton` is being held onto until sometime later, presumably the next iteration of the runloop. It's odd and I can't put my finger immediately on what exactly will be holding onto it, but that's all it is. Why do you care?

Comment: @mattjgalloway I'm curious at to whether other classes might be affected by this behaviour. In the specific app I'm working on at the moment I have an `AVAssetReader` object being created for each iteration of a `while(rarelyFalse)` loop -- I'm noticing that memory is steadily increasing, only released once the loop ends, exhibiting the same behaviour as the `UIButton` in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I have done some more thinking about this, together with the great contributions from **bbum** and **Wade Tegaskis** regarding blocking the runloop, and realised that the way to mitigate this sort of issue is by letting the runloop cycle, by using the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` which lets the runloop continue, whilst scheduling the loop to continue itself in the future.

For example, to return to my original example with the `UIButton`, this should now be rewritten as a method like this:-

```
- (void)spawnButton {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectZero;
    [self performSelector:@selector(spawnButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

This way, the method ends immediately and `button` is correctly released when it goes out of scope, but in the final line, `spawnButton` instructs the runloop to run `spawnButton` again in 0 seconds (i.e. as soon as possible), which in turn instructs the runloop to run... etc etc, you get the idea.

All you then need to do is call `[self spawnButton]` somewhere else in the code to get the cycle going.

This can also be solved similarly using GCD, with the following code which essentially does the same thing:

```
- (void)spawnButton {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectZero;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self spawnButton];
    });
}
```

The only difference here is that the method call is dispatched (asynchronously) onto the main queue (main runloop) using GCD.

Profiling it in Instruments I can now see that although the overall allocation memory is going up, the live memory remains low and static, showing that the runloop is cycling and the old `UIButton`s are being deallocated.

By thinking about runloops like this, and using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or GCD, there are actually a number of other instances (not just with UIKit) where this sort of approach can prevent unintentional "memory leaks" caused by runloop lockups (I use that in quotations because in this case I was being a UIKit rogue.. but there are other cases where this technique is useful.)

Answer (score 6):

As to why the UI* objects grow without bounds?  Internal implementation detail.  Most likely, some kind of cache or runloop interaction that you are effectively disabling by blocking the main run loop.

Which brings me to the real answer:

> Most importantly, how can I keep the heap from expanding endlessly
>   when using UIKit classes in an endless loop like this, and what does
>   this tell us about the best practices for ARC in while(true) or
>   while(keepRunningForALongTime) style loops?

How to fix it?   **Do not ever use a tight loop on the main thread** and **Do not ever block the main run loop**.

Even if you were to figure out and workaround the UI* induced heap growth, your program still wouldn't work if you were to use a `while(...)` loop on the main thread.   The entire design of iOS applications -- and Cocoa applications -- is that the main thread has a main run loop and that main run loop must be free to run.

If not?  Your app will not be responsive (and will eventually be killed by the system) to user input and your drawing code is unlikely to work as expected (since the run loop coalesces dirty regions and draws them on demand in conjunction with the main thread, oft offloading to a secondary thread).

Answer (score 1):

Speculation on my part here, but, it could boil down to the fact that UI-related objects especially tend to use GCD or similar (e.g. performSelectorOnMainThread:…) to ensure some actions happen on the main thread.  This is as you suspect - the enqueued block or other unit of execution maintains a reference to the instance, waiting for its time in the runloop to execute, and never getting it.

As a rule it's bad to block the runloop.  Once upon a time it used to be relatively common - drag tracking was often done this way (or effectively so, by running the runloop only in a special mode while the drag progressed).  But it leads to weird interactions and even deadlocks, because lots of code isn't designed with the possibility in mind - especially in a GCD world where asynchronousity is king.

Remember that you can run the runloop explicitly if you like, inside your while loop, and while that's not quite identical to letting it run naturally, it usually works.